# Mysql: indexed count query vs maintaining summary table

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

I am working on an e-commerce website where user can show interest on available products and we store it as a lead in mysql table. This `Leads` table consists of millions of records and grows by 8 records per seconds. Table structure is as follows:

```
LeadId | ProductId | UserId | RequestDate(DateTime)
```

Table Schema:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ProductId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`RequestDateTime` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ix_leads_requestdatetime` (`RequestDateTime`) USING BTREE,
KEY `ix_leads_productid` (`ProductId`) USING BTREE,
KEY `ix_leads_userid` (`UserID`) USING BTREE
```

Now, the requirement is to allow one user to give maximum 10 leads in a day. I have following approaches to implement this:

1. Select query to count number of records for that day in `Leads` table and check if < 20 before insertion.
2. Maintain a `DailyLeadCount` table which contains count of leads for each `userId` for particular date. Table Structure:

   ```
   UserId | Date | Count
   ```

   Table Schema:

   ```
   `RequestDate` date NOT NULL,
   `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `LeadCount` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`RequestDate`,`UserId`)
   ```

   I will check count in this table before inserting in `Leads` table and update this count after insertion accordingly. Also, as only one day data will be useful in this table, I will create a job to archive it daily.

Which approach is better? Is running select query on `Leads` table to get count more heavy than insert/update and select query on `DailyLeadCount` table?

Is it worth maintaining and archiving a table daily for it?

Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: A third option would be to construct your insert statement to include the check in a where clause with a sub-query. Can you show the table schema, including indexes?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Added table schema. And, adding the subquery in where clause is equal to approach-1 in terms of performance if it is in stored procedure. Isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly equal. With #1, you have two separate queries, the select and the insert. Best way to find out is to write both queries and use Explain to see how the server perceives the work to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
KEY `ix_leads_userid` (`UserID`) USING BTREE
```

to

```
INDEX(UserID, RequestDateTime)
```

Then spit at the user when

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Leads WHERE UserID = 1234
       AND RequestDateTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
) >= 10
```

The query will be fast enough to do in real time.

The count is between this time yesterday and now -- this may not be exactly what you want.  If, instead, you want the clock to start at midnight this morning:

```
       AND RequestDateTime > CURDATE()
```

If "since midnight yesterday":

```
       AND RequestDateTime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If you want to use *his* timezone for midnight, it gets messier.

Potential issue:  If he can somehow batch his leads, he could insert multiple leads in the same millisecond.  (I am noticing `DATETIME(3)`.)

Your idea of a Summary Table works best if you need to check against "yesterday", not so well for "the last 86400000 milliseconds".

Comment: I am a bit confused about when a summary table is better. I need to check the count of the "current date" (i.e. clock resets at midnight this day), not for last 24 hours. If you are saying summary won't work for last "x" unit time but will work better for "last date". Wouldn't it be useful in my case (current date)?

Comment: If you are only looking at "today", then you don't need to summarize previous days.  And summarizing "today" is best done after midnight tonight.